# Mobile website sometimes opens phone app when tapping anywhere on page

Tags: html, mobile

http://ruurdbijlsma.com/

If you tap on some of the elements on this page it opens the phone app for some reason. I haven't got a tel: link anywhere on the page. I do have a phonenumber in a `<p>` tag there though, but that shouldn't open the phone app.

This is what happens on my phone: https://youtu.be/kYRc3Kcw0ew

The phone number it opens is the one in the p tag at the bottom of the page.
The only selectable text on the page is the phone number and the email adress, this is probably part of the problem. It seems that it only happens in Chrome on mobile, I've tested Firefox and it doesn't happen there.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the site from opening the phone app?